# hashtag and query string interchange in the URL

Tags: javascript, java, xml, xslt

My URL having both the hsahtag to open a hide and show and follwed by a tracking URL(query string)  e.g as below http://pre-live/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us#Group?clickpage=information-en--group-travel--index&kmtag=c&ban=||SH|2|CTA1|||||CampID||||L2|||||||

The issue is #Group is not working properly due to the Query string follwed by it, it will work when we place the hash tag at last.

like this http://pre-live/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us?clickpage=information-en--group-travel--index&kmtag=c&ban=||SH|2|CTA1|||||CampID||||L2|||||||#Group

so could any one suggest on this.

below is my xslt part

```
<div class="linkContainer">
    <!-- Check if the URL we're tracking is internal (BA) or external, if it is internal it will return true-->
    <xsl:variable name="trackingURL">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="trackingURL">
            <xsl:with-param name="trackURL" select="linkURL" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="link">
    <xsl:value-of select="linkURL"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="hash">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($link, '#')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="linkURL">
    <xsl:if test="contains($link, '#')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($link, '#')"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(contains($link, '#'))">
    <xsl:value-of select="$link"/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
        <a href="$PAGE_LINK[{$linkURL}]" title="{$titleTag}">
           <xsl:if test="linkOpenStyle = 'newWindow'">
                <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
             <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:if test="linkStyle='primary'">ui-priority-primary <xsl:value-of select="$linkStyleVal"/></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="linkStyle='secondary'">ui-priority-secondary <xsl:value-of select="$linkStyleVal"/></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="linkStyle='text'"><xsl:value-of select="$linkStyleVal"/></xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!-- Tracking params -->
        <!-- It uses "self::node()" to apply the template to itself. We use that instead of "." because you can't use predicates on that. The params add the data attributes needed for tracking to work -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()[$tracking = 'yes' and $trackingURL = 'true']" mode="trackingParams">
            <xsl:with-param name="click-position">
                <xsl:apply-templates  mode="buttonType" />
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <!-- End Tracking -->
            <xsl:value-of select="linkText" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </a>            
    </div>
```

Now i have removed the hashtag from the url, i am not sure where and how to place this in the href value.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note, is that you can use an `xsl:choose` in your existing code, to avoid duplicating the `contains` test.

```
<xsl:variable name="linkURL">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($link, '#')">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($link, '#')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="$link"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Having said that, you can achieve what you want in single statements. To get the `hash` you need to get the text after the "#" but you need to cater for if it comes before or after the query string. The trick is to append a dummy "?" to the link you use in the expression.

```
<xsl:variable name="hash" select="substring-before(substring-after(concat($link, '?'), '#'), '?')" />
```

You can use a similar to trick to get the rest of the URL without the hash. This has two parts, one to get the part before the hash, the other after.

```
 <xsl:variable name="linkURL">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($link, '#'), '#')" />
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($link, concat('#', $hash))" />
 </xsl:variable>
```

In the case no hash is present, the first statement gets the entire URL, and  second statement returns nothing.

For example, given this XML

```
<links>
    <link>
        <linkURL>http://pre-live/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us#Group?clickpage=information-en--group-travel--index&amp;kmtag=c&amp;ban=||SH|2|CTA1|||||CampID||||L2|||||||</linkURL>    
    </link>
    <link>
        <linkURL>http://pre-live/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us?clickpage=information-en--group-travel--index&amp;kmtag=c&amp;ban=||SH|2|CTA1|||||CampID||||L2|||||||#Group</linkURL>    
    </link>
    <link>
        <linkURL>http://pre-live/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us?clickpage=information-en--group-travel--index&amp;kmtag=c&amp;ban=||SH|2|CTA1|||||CampID||||L2|||||||</linkURL>    
    </link>
</links>
```

The following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="link">
        <xsl:variable name="link" select="linkURL"/>
        <xsl:variable name="hash" select="substring-before(substring-after(concat($link, '?'), '#'), '?')" />
        <xsl:variable name="linkURL">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($link, '#'), '#')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($link, concat('#', $hash))" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <linkURL>
                <xsl:value-of select="$linkURL" />
            </linkURL>
            <hash>
                <xsl:value-of select="$hash" />
            </hash>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces this output

```
<link>
   <linkURL>http://pre-live/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us?clickpage=information-en--group-travel--index&amp;kmtag=c&amp;ban=||SH|2|CTA1|||||CampID||||L2|||||||</linkURL>
   <hash>Group</hash>
</link>
<link>
   <linkURL>http://pre-live/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us?clickpage=information-en--group-travel--index&amp;kmtag=c&amp;ban=||SH|2|CTA1|||||CampID||||L2|||||||</linkURL>
   <hash>Group</hash>
</link>
<link>
   <linkURL>http://pre-live/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us?clickpage=information-en--group-travel--index&amp;kmtag=c&amp;ban=||SH|2|CTA1|||||CampID||||L2|||||||</linkURL>
   <hash/>
</link>
```